# Preloading images and audio with a progress bar in React

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I am implementing some activities where users will be able to click on various pictures and have it play a sound. Images and audio should be loaded ahead of time so that it provides a clean experience for the user. For this both images and audio will need to be preloaded.

During loading of images/audio file I would like a progress bar to be displayed. If images/audio are in the browser's cache already then there should be no need to display a progress bar (or to display it very briefly).

I have seen the `react-preload` library, but it seems to only work with images.

The `react-circular-progressbar` is easy enough to use for a progress bar, but I am unclear as to how I would get it to work with preloading.

How do I go about implementing preloading of both images and audio with a progress bar in React?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't have any JavaScript code used to preload images and audio.  You can use the Fetch API to preload them:

```
fetch('https://somesite.com/my_image.png')
.then(resp => resp.blob())
.then(blob => {
   let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   let img = new Image();
   // Image loading is an asynchronous operation
   img.onload = e => console.log('async', img.naturalWidth, img.complete);
   img.src = url;
});
```

Essentially, you need to write your Progress Bar logic in the function which is run on the "onload" event. The way we did it is that we know how many images and audio we need to load, so we use the counter of preloaded multimedia (you increase it by 1 on each run of the "onload" function) and then compare it with the total number of multimedia that needs to be preloaded. This is the information that your Progress Bar uses.

Comment: Can you clarify a few questions: 1) Does the img.src begins to load the image in the browser cache? 2) When it does get loaded in the browser cache then img.onLoad is invoked and img.complete will always have the value of true (assuming it could find the image) 3) What are the implications of images that are already in the browser cache? Does onload return right away with img.complete = true? 4) I realize that I probably need to use readyState four audio, but would using a blob approach for audio work the same way as you mention here.

Comment: 1) The browser will always try to load the image in the cache first, even when doing it this way. If the image is not in the cache, it will be downloaded.
2) Yes, when it gets loaded, the img.onload will be invoked and img.complete will be true if it successfully finds it.
3) Even if the image is already in the cache, it is not guaranteed that "onload" will return right away. You should always treat this as an asynchronouos operation.
4) Yes, I have experience with loading images, audio and video this way.